# Why are strings sent via Multipeer Connectivity garbled on the receiving end?

Tags: ios, swift, multipeer-connectivity

I'm working on an augmented reality application where multiple users can connect and see the same virtual content. I'm using Apple's Multipeer Connectivity framework for communication, but am having trouble sending and receiving a string between two connected peers.

The idea is when a SCNNode is added to the user's virtual space, Multipeer will send the node's position in 3D space, its color, and its size across the peer-to-peer network, and the receiving peers can add the same content to their space.

I build the string like so:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    let nodeColor = node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents
    let nodePosition = node.position
    let dataString = "x: \(nodePosition.x) y: \(nodePosition.y) z: \(nodePosition.z) color: \(nodeColor!) radius: \(sphereRadius)"
    let dataToSend = dataString.data(using: .utf8)
    MultiPeer.instance.send(data: dataToSend!)
}
```

---

Here's the function that sends the data:

```
public func send(data: Data){
    if isConnected {
        do {
            let item = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: data, requiringSecureCoding: true)
            try session.send(item, toPeers: session.connectedPeers, with: MCSessionSendDataMode.reliable)
        } catch let error {
            printDebug(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

---

And on the receiving end:

```
public func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive data: Data, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
    let incomingString = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
    print(incomingString)
}
```

---

I tested the code by sending strings, and this is the output on the receiving end from three of those strings:

```
Troot�#-27:@����bplist00�X$versionX$objectsY$archiverT$top:-0.04734481 z: -0.019065317 color: UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1 radius: 0.01_NSKeyedArchiver�

Troot�#-27:@����bplist00�X$versionX$objectsY$archiverT$topIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1 radius: 0.01_NSKeyedArchiver�

Troot�#-27:@����bplist00� X$versionX$objectsY$archiverT$top\277\275U$nullOax: 0.01673067 y: -0.048672535 z: -0.02221658 color: UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1 radius: 0.01_NSKeyedArchiver�
```

---

Clearly the string is being sent and received, but not without extra characters and symbols.
Any input is appreciated, thanks!

UPDATE: Martin R. pointed out I'm not using NSKeyedUnarchiver to decode the string. I've since updated my code to use it:

```
let receivedData = data
let receivedString = String(data: receivedData, encoding: .utf8)
print("Received data \(String(describing: receivedString))")


do {
    let unarchiver = try NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingFrom: receivedData)
    let decodedString = unarchiver.decodeData()
    print("Decoded string: \(String(describing: decodedString))")
}catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

The string is no longer garbled, but it's nil. This is true before decoding it, so the string is nil when received by the peer.

Comment: Think about it: If the sender uses NSKeyedArchiver to pack the data, then the receiver must use NSKeyedUnarchiver to unpack it.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you, I can't believe I missed that! However, now I'm receiving a nil string instead it being garbled. I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Martin R. solved the issue of symbols being added with the suggestion of using NSKeyedUnarchiver to unpack the data. After that, I found the strings were nil on the receiving end. Changing

```
do {
    let unarchiver = try NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingFrom: receivedData)
    let decodedString = unarchiver.decodeData()
    print("Decoded string: \(String(describing: decodedString))")
}catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

to

```
do {
    let decodedString = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(receivedData)
    print("Decoded string: \(String(describing: decodedString))")
}catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Fixed the issue and the strings are now being sent and received properly.